# C# devolve uma string HTML

Tags: c#, html, culture

Boas,

Eu uso o seguinte código para converter um valor numérico de acordo com a cultura do utilizador:

```
value="@(Model.KnowAcquisition.Cost.HasValue ? Model.KnowAcquisition.Cost.Value.ToString("n2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString() : string.Empty)" />
```

No entanto, o C# transforma nisto:

```
<input type="text" class="famo-input famo-text-10" name="cost" value="1&nbsp;000,25">
```

O meu problema é que deveria de ser um espaço em vez do `&nbsp`. Já testei com strings normais e mostra o espaço, apenas quando utilizo o ToString() com uma cultura associada é que ele mostra o `&nbsp`.

Como é que posso alterar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já encontrei uma solução, tinha que fazer um replace no C#:

```
@{ 
    string cost = (Model.KnowAcquisition.Cost.HasValue ? Model.KnowAcquisition.Cost.Value.ToString("n2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) : string.Empty).Replace("\u00A0", " ");
}

<input type="text" class="famo-input famo-text-10" name="cost" value="@cost" />
```

Aparentemente, o NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator é igual ao Non-Breaking Space.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [Html.Raw()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) para que não haja codificação HTML na string.

Ficaria assim:

```
<input type="text" class="famo-input famo-text-10" name="cost" value="@Html.Raw(Model.KnowAcquisition.Cost.HasValue ? Model.KnowAcquisition.Cost.Value.ToString("n2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString() : string.Empty)" />
```

Tente também, da seguinte forma (utilizando [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx)), caso a string já esteja codificada para HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="famo-input famo-text-10" name="cost" value="@Html.Raw(Model.KnowAcquisition.Cost.HasValue ? HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.KnowAcquisition.Cost.Value.ToString("n2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString()) : string.Empty)" />
```

Comment: eu ainda não testei...mas existe alguma explicação porque funciona com umas strings e com outras não?

Comment: Existe. São caracteres especiais em HTML, que possuem um encode diferente. Por isso eles são substituídos por outros equivalentes. Eis aqui alguns exemplos: http://erikasarti.net/html/acentuacao-caracteres-especiais/

Comment: Peço desculpa mas não percebi, eu se colocasse no HTML a string "ola mundo", o espaço aparece. Esta string tem um espaço e aparece com um caracter especial...é isso que não percebo.

Comment: Uma coisa, a solução não funciona. Continua a aparecer o `&nbsp`.

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta com uma possível solução, já que o encode HTML continua ocorrendo

Comment: Continua a não funcionar....
Já experimentei formatar datas e aparecem os espaços...simplesmente não consigo perceber

Comment: Bom.. infelizmente não consigo te ajudar mais, nesse caso já escapou do meu campo de conhecimento, sugiro verificar o charset do seu documento HTML e verificar se aplicar a cultura no `.ToString()` influência de mais alguma forma a renderização da view.